# Return a &Vec<T> from a VecDeque<T> field

Tags: rust

I have a type with a [`VecDeque<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html) field and a `get() -> Option<&Vec<T>>` method:

```rust
struct Storage<T> {
    buffer: VecDeque<T>
}

impl<T> Storage<T> {
    fn get(&self, /* args */ ) -> Option<&Vec<T>> { /* ... */ }
}
```

Based on the input arguments to `get()` I would like to return an `Option<&Vec<T>>` that essentially refers to the slice from index `i` to index `j` inside the `buffer`:

```
index  =  0 ... i ... j  ... (n-1)
buffer = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
                |-----|
             return &Vec<T>
```

In my attempts so far I see that [`VecDeque::as_slices()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.as_slices) might help (I ensure the buffer is always contiguous before `get()` is called) and I also see that there are ways to convert slices into a `Vec<T>`. Its the reference part `&Vec<T>` that I seem to be having trouble with.

**Additional Details:** The `get()` method actually comes from the implementation of a trait:

```
trait Storable {
    type OutputType;
    fn get(&self, /* args */) -> Option<&Self::OutputType>;
}
```

This API is following that of the `Slab` type from the [slab](https://docs.rs/slab/0.4.3/slab/struct.Slab.html) crate and, in fact, implementing `Storable` for `Slab` is very straightforward. One possibility is that I change the `OutputType` associated type from `Vec<T>` to something else. However, elsewhere in my code I might be relying heavily on the assumption that this associated type is a `Vec<T>`. That's probably a code smell. Whatever the solution might be, I want to avoid copy/clones as much as possible for performance reasons.

Comment: Are you sure you need `&Vec<T>`? An `&Vec<T>` is almost never useful, perhaps you could do with `&[T]` instead. To do so, you could set `type OutputType = [T]`, which will cause `Storable::get()` to return `Option<&[T]>`. If you make sure the `VecDeque` is contiguous, that should be exactly what you need.

Comment: The input/output of other types I've build that implement the `Storable` trait are `Vec<T>`. Because of the way these other types stored the `Vec<T>`s, the storage type can own those vecs. However, the type I created above that uses a `VecDeque<T>` doesn't actually store the vectors, hence the problem. While I'm not opposed to it, I'll need to see the impact of switching to `&[T]` types.

Comment: It sounds like you have painted yourself into a corner with abstractions. I don't mean that as a criticism, it happens to literally everyone who does non-trivial programming. Good luck with figuring out an elegant solution that works!

Comment: At least the rest of the living room looks nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this isn't possible in the way you imagine it to happen, because of ownership rules:

If you get your deque as slices, then you'll get your single contiguous slice, which is essentially an immutable borrow. That means the slice doesn't own the values. Its type will be `&[T]`.

Now a `Vec<T>` on the other hand will want to *own* the values of type T. So creating a `Vec<T>` from a `&[T]` will have to involve either a copy or a clone, depending on whether `T` supports either of those operations.

The fact that you want a `&Vec<T>` doesn't change the fact that somewhere you'd need to create the actual `Vec<T>` on the heap, which in turns requires changing ownership.

Another issue with returning `&Vec<T>` is that of lifetime. If this `Vec` is freshly created, through whatever conversion you figure out works for you, it'll be only valid as long as it lives, which would be the `get` function:

```rust
impl<T> Storage<T> {
  fn get(&self, /* args*/ ) -> Option<&Vec<T>> {
    let return_vec: Vec<T> = /* some code */;
    /* some more code */
    Ok(&return_vec); // Uh oh!
  }
}
```

The compiler will complain that you can't return a reference to something that's local in a function.

I think the best option is to just change the output type to be a slice, `&[T]`. You say that in your own internal code you rely heavily on the vec representation. Now the nice thing is that via some smart trait implementations, any functions that expects `&[T]` as an argument will also just work for `Vec<T>`.

Comment: You comment about `Vec<T>` wanting to own its values makes my issue clear. You can rephrase my question as: "does Rust have a `Span` C++ object"? (A non-owning vector.) The `return_vec` example was actually one of my failed attempts. Like you say, `&[T]` shouldn't be too much of an issue. We'll see!

Comment: A non-owning vector would have type `Vec<&T>`.

Comment: Here is how `Vec<&T>` would work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef65f72631fe44b9557ff4953b5c2231

Comment: I comment above that the `Option<&OutputType>` design was borrowed from `Slab` and that some of my other implementations of `Storable` naturally adhered to this design. (For example, a `HashMap`-based storage would own its `Vec<T>`'s.